# Count with last 4 digits which represent Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question

Can we convert date 20-06-2011 (dd-mm-yyyy) into 0611 using sql (SQL server database) ?

And

Can we count ID below
keeping in mind last 4 digits which represent date (last 4 digits represent date in the form MMYY) so numbers with last 4 digits 0611 count should be 3

What would be the SQl Query for the count?

```
ID

AOB2340511
AOB4560511
AOB3500611
AOB4410611
AOB5120611
AOB1250411
```

Comment: Your first question is valid, your second question is very difficult to understand. Also you have 5 questions with answers that you have not accepted. If you accept answers people will be more willing to answer your question.

Comment: I had accepted the answers. What can I do to show that I accepted them

Comment: For each answer for your question, you'll find a check mark.  Click on the check mark next to the answer that is best for your question.

Comment: They aren't accepted. You have to click on the green check mark. Read the FAQ for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I have accepted 3 of them now. Clicked on check mark to do it. Thanks for the advice guys :)

Comment: Anyone has the answer for this question?

Comment: Count is 3  for    ID   which ends with 0611   How can you count it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Corrected DATE data type option.

If your date fields are DATE data types you can do the following.

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(MM, @TheDate) as VARCHAR), 2)
    + RIGHT(CAST(DATEPART(YY, @TheDate) as VARCHAR), 2)
```

If your date fields are stored as a string type, such as VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, etc, then try the following

```
select SUBSTRING(TheDate, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(TheDate, 9, 2)
```

For the question about count, you can try this

```
SELECT RIGHT(ID, 4) AS TheDate, Count(*) AS TheCount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY RIGHT(ID, 4)
```

If you need a query for the count that also shows the ID value, give this a try

```
SELECT ID, RIGHT(ID, 4) as MMYY,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY RIGHT(ID, 4)) AS TheGroupCount
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you "YYMM":

SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),12),1,4)

To get the 2-digit month before the 2-digit year you need to do:

SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),12),3,2) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate(),12),1,2)

getdate() is just the current datestamp; substitute that with the date field you want to reformat.
CONVERT(...,12) gives you YYMMDD datestamp. See this helpful page for more magic numbers to use as the 3rd parameter: http://sql.dzone.com/news/custom-date-formatting-sql-ser

(BTW, using DATEPART(MM,getdate()) gives a 1-digit month not 2 digits, and DATEPART(YY,getdate()) gives a 4-digit year, not 2 digits. I.e. the DATEPART approach seems doomed)

Comment: A comment explaining my mistake would have been more appropriate.  But, if you just want credit for a better answer, you got it.

Comment: Hi Bobs, I fully agree, but as my account is still new I don't have permission to leave comments (except on my own answers it seems); so I had to add it as a postscript to my own answer (which I'd been writing in parallel to yours).